# Implementing variable replacement in a boolean polynomial function in Coq

Tags: function, coq

I have a boolean polynomial function of the form

```coq
Definition poly (m n : nat) := bv m -> bv n -> C.
```

Where `bv dim` is simply a boolean list of length `dim` defined as `Definition bv (n : nat) := list bool.`.

Now, I want to be able to replace the variables of some polynomial P, i.e., perform P[x <- x'][y <- y'], where x is the first list and y the second one. How could I implement this?

For example, given a function P(x, y) = x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1. The replacement P' = P[[x_0, x_1] <- [x_1, x_0]][y <- y] would give me the new function P'(x, y) = x_1 y_0 + x_0 y_1.

I was thinking something along the lines of the following, but this would give a constant function for any inputs.

```coq
Definition replace_poly {m n : nat} (p : poly m n) (nx : bv m) (ny : bv n) : poly m width :=
    fun x y => p nx ny.
```

Therefore, I'm not sure how to implement what I want.

Comment: What is exactly the encoding of `x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1` as a `poly 2 2`?

Comment: That would be `Definition ex : phase_poly 2 2 := fun x y => (get_bv 0 x * get_bv 0 y) + (get_bv 1 x * get_bv 1 y)`, where `get_bv i v` gets the ith element of a boolean list v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to precompose your polynomial by a function from lists to lists, which implements the substitution. In your specific example (I assume `P` takes 2 x-variables and 1 y-variable, but of course you can adapt this):

```coq
Hypothesis get {m : nat} (n : nat) : bv m : bool.
(* gets the n-th boolean in a list *)
Hypothesis (nil : bv 0) (cons : forall n, bool -> bv n -> bv (S n)). 
Definition rename (x : bv 2) : bv 2 :=
  cons 1 (get 0 x) (cons 0 (get 1 x) nil).

Definition replace_poly {m n : nat} (p : poly 2 1) : poly 2 1 :=
    fun x y => p (rename x) y.
```